# Можно ли через AsyncTask получить текст из ресурса с помошью getResources

Tags: android, строки, listview, android-asynctask

В файле strings.xml

есть массив ресурсов

```
  <string-array name="cat_names">
    <item>текст</item>
    <item>текст2</item>
    <item>текст3</item>
    <item>текст4</item>
    <item>текст5</item>
    ......
</string-array>
```

получить ресурс можно с помощью

```
String[] catnames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat_names);
```

Но массивов несколько и в каждом массиве очень много текста. При выводе этого всего в списке приложение немного притормаживает, вроде мелочь, но не приятно.

Есть ли возможность в Андроид Студио весь этот вывод ресурсов вставить в AsyncTask?

Код который я привел внизу очень некрасивый)) но я думаю идея понятно. Вроде все логично, но не работает вылетает ошибка

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
String[] catnames5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    // если раскомментировать, то работает, но нужно этот код как нибудь засунуть в AsyncTask
    //catnames5 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat_names);


    // выводим
    MyTask mt = new MyTask();
    mt.execute();
    catnames5 = mt.catnames4;

    // используем адаптер данных
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, catnames5);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

// 
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String title;
    String[] catnames2;
    String[] catnames4;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String[] catnames = null;

        try {
            catnames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat_names);
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (catnames!=null)
            catnames2 = catnames;
        else
            title = "Ошибка";

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        catnames4 = catnames2;
    }
}
```

}

лог ошибки

```
08-23 19:36:34.932 2353-2353/net.artsait.asunk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: net.artsait.asunk, PID: 2353
                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.artsait.asunk/net.artsait.asunk.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
                                                                 at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
                                                                 at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)
                                                                 at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:137)
                                                                 at net.artsait.asunk.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Вылетает здесь

```
at net.artsait.asunk.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
```

Ну или при использование адаптара

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, catnames5);
```

Хотя адаптар работает если просто в onCreate вставить строку

```
String[] catnames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat_names);
```

Но как вставить эту строку в AsyncTask

Comment: Без сообщения об ошибке вам не помочь. И надо в онПостЕкз передавать значение и там его присваивать

Comment: А на какой строке падает?

Comment: Вылетает здесь

    at net.artsait.asunk.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)

Ну или при использование адаптара

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, catnames5);

Хотя адаптар работает если просто в onCreate вставить строку

    String[] catnames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat_names);
    
Но как вставить эту строку в AsyncTask

Comment: Вы написали номер строки, но тут нет нумерации строк кода. Так что вы так и не сказали на какой строке вылетает

Comment: Я же написал, вылетает ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, catnames5);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsyncTask` -  это асинхронная задача, запустив которую точно нельзя сказать когда она закончиться. В вашем случае, когда вы отображаете список на основании данных  которые подгружаются из `AsyncTask` - список может проинициализироваться еще когда `Async` не закончил работу. Для того что бы отобразать список только тогда когда у вас уже есть нужные данные можно сделать `Callback`  с `AsyncTask`. Ниже я приведу код с помощью которого можно получить результат из таска и с этими данными уже создать `ListView`. Возможно это не лучший вариант в том плане, что список отобразиться только когда отработает `AsyncTask`, правильней было бы все таки сделать так: отобразить пустой список -> подгрузить данные в таске -> обновить `ListView` уже с новыми данными, но это уже совсем другая история.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
String[] catnames5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    // если раскомментировать, то работает, но нужно этот код как нибудь засунуть в AsyncTask
    //catnames5 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat_names);


    // выводим
    MyTask mt = new MyTask(new MyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String[] array) {
            // используем адаптер данных
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed() {
            //тут можно обработать вариант если ошибка
       }
    });

    mt.execute();

}

    public interface MyCallback {
        void onComplete(String[] array);

        void onFailed();
    }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String title;
        String[] catnames2;
        String[] catnames4;

        MyCallback callback;

        public MyTask(MyCallback callback) {
            this.callback = callback;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            String[] catnames = null;

            try {
                catnames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat_names);
            } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (callback != null) {
                if (catnames != null) {
                    catnames2 = catnames;
                    callback.onComplete(catnames);
                } else {
                    title = "Ошибка";
                    callback.onFailed();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            catnames4 = catnames2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Подчеркивает красным
this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);

Comment: замените на getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0):

Изначально переменная `catnames4` ровна `null`. Ее инициализация происходит только после выполнения `MyTask` в методе `onPostExecute`. То есть не успевает выполнится `MyTask` до создание адаптера. В адаптер в переменной 'catnames5' идет значение null. Создайте и присвойте адаптер в методе 'onPostExecute', правда тормоза останутся. Вообще нет смысла в `MyTask`, пока данных не будет и отображать в списке нечего. Если тебе надо чтобы приложение быстрее запустилось, а список позже загрузился. Тогда попробуй разместить код в `onStart` или `onResume`

```
@Override
public void onStart() {

    String[] catnames = null;

    try {
        catnames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat_names);
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // используем адаптер данных
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, catnames);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```